# COOKIE creada en php se lee mal en JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, html5

Tengo el siguiente problema, creo una cookie en PHP para luego leerla en javascript e imprimirla y pasa esto. No se como corregirlo. Ayuda porfavor.

**Leo así la cookie en javascript:**

```
var micookie = (document.cookie.indexOf('resultado=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; resultado=')[1].split(';')[0]);
```

Así creó la cookie en PHP:

```
setcookie("resultado","success",time() + 1, "/kira");
```

Y se imprime así, como veis en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código que crea la notificación**

```
var i = -1;
var toastCount = 0;
var $toastlast;

var micookie = (document.cookie.indexOf('resultado=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; resultado=')[1].split(';')[0]);
var micookietipo = (document.cookie.indexOf('tipo_result=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; tipo_result=')[1].split(';')[0]);
var micookiedesc = (document.cookie.indexOf('desc_result=') === -1 ? '' : ("; " + document.cookie).split('; desc_result=')[1].split(';')[0]);

function alerta() {


    var shortCutFunction = micookie;

    var msg = micookiedesc || '';

    var title = micookietipo || '';

    var $showDuration = $(300);

    var $hideDuration = $(1000);

    var $timeOut = $(2000);

    var $extendedTimeOut = $(500);



    var toastIndex = toastCount++;



    var addClear = $('#addClear').prop('checked');



    toastr.options = {

        closeButton: false,

        debug: false,

        newestOnTop: false,

        progressBar: true,

        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right' || 'toast-top-right',

        preventDuplicates: true,

        onclick: null

    };



    toastr.options.showEasing = 'swing';



    toastr.options.hideEasing = 'linear';



    toastr.options.showMethod = 'fadeIn';



    toastr.options.hideMethod = 'fadeOut';


    var $toast = toastr[shortCutFunction](msg, title); // Wire up an event handler to a button in the toast, if it exists

    $toastlast = $toast;


    if (typeof $toast === 'undefined') {

        return;

    }

};

if (typeof micookie !== 'undefined' && typeof micookietipo !== 'undefined' && typeof micookiedesc !== 'undefined') {
    alerta();
}
```

Comment: Falraria el codigo con el que generas el cartel

Comment: Ya esta tambien subido

Comment: Hola, es necesario colocar ese mensaje en cookie? intenta mejor hacer esos mensaje en variable de sesión.